# Prove for a sequence ($a_n$)$_n$ with converging partial sum $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$ it holds that for a bounded, monotonically decreasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

Prove that for a sequence ($a_n$)$_n$
with converging partial sum
$$s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$$ , it holds that for a bounded, monotonically decreasing sequence ($c_n$)$_n$, the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nc_n$$ converges.

---

They gave us some hints, but I'm a bit confused:

$c_n \to c$

$x_n := c_n - c$

$\lim_{n  \to \infty}x_n = 0 \checkmark$

$x_n \searrow 0$

$x_{n+1} \leq x_n$

$c_{n+1} - c \leq c_n - c$

$c_{n+1} \leq c_n$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nc_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(c_n - c + c) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(c_n - c) + a_nc$$

Also, they said we should read about Abel's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem

That's what I did but I'm still confused about how to proceed. Any help or hint would be welcome, Thank you !

Comment: My idea was that $c_n$ converges to $c$ so the term $c_n - c$ will give $0$, thus $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(c_n - c) + a_nc = 0 + a_nc = a_nc$ but I don't know if this helps, or what to do next

Comment: This exact statement is wrong since you haven't imposed any additional assumption about the sequences. For example, consider $a_n=n^2$ and $c_n=\frac{1}{n}$. Then $(c_n)_n$ is bounded and decreases monotonically, but the series of the product does not converge.

Comment: Another counterexample: Even if $(a_n)_n$ converges to $0$, e.g. $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$, the statement is not true (consider $c_n=1+\frac{1}{n}$).

Comment: @math-jl I forgot the word "converging" for the partial sum, does it change something ?

Comment: The statement is a special case of [Abel’s test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test), you could see [here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_12/Abel.pdf) for a proof.